# How to test ARKit app? Can ARKit app be tested using recorded video instead of live video?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit

Getting started with ARKit development.  Imagine that testing an app in development between builds requires imaging an environment to expose the app to a scene and that having to physically hold and/or move camera to capture live scene will be extremely cumbersome each time.

Can an app be tested with recorded video in order to avoid having to capture a realtime scene each time an app has to be tested?  If so, how to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no other way to test ARKit apps except running them on your device. I agree, it is a cumbersome process, but for now thats all we have. Hopefully, in the future, Apple will make some sort of AR simulator so that we can test our apps in a faster and easier way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can record videos using Reality Composer, then airdrop them to your mac, add them to your Xcode project, edit the scheme to enable ARKit "Replay data" (it may only appear when a device is connected), then select your video in the drop-down list

[image: arkit-replay-data-in-xcode]

Edit : screenshot made using Xcode 12.5.1

Comment: How can we achieve this by code?

Comment: no idea, maybe you should ask Apple with a DTS